# Why python goes in loop and takes up to 40% of my CPU?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I was testing some code, and for some reason python can't get to the end of the code, taking up to 40% of my CPU.

```py
import random

input_text = input('Testo > ')
key = ''
output_text = ''
cond_1 = ''

alfabeto = list("qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM 1234567890èéòç@à°#ù§[]+*,;.:-_<>£$₽%&()=?ì^/|!ėëęēêĖËĘĒÉÈÊūûüúŪÛÜÚÙīïįíìîĪÏĮÍÌÎºōøõœöôóŌØÕŒÖÓÒãåāáâäæÃÅĀªÀÁÂÄÆßẞÇñÑ¥¢∆¶×÷π√•`~©®™✓йцукенгшщзхфывапролджэячсмитьбюЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮ⌂☻‼‰╛┐└┴┬├─┼╞╟╚╔╩╦╠═╬╧╨╤▬╥╙╘╒╓╫╪┘┌¤█▄▌▐▀αΣσ░▒▓│┤╡╢╖╕╣║╗╝¿þ¼½¾ⁿ⌠⌡≤≥±≡∩∞ΘΩð«»⌐¬¨↨↑↓→←↔₧☼♥♦♣♠♂♀♪◘○◙►◄▲▼Þ‘’“”„")
numeri = ''

for _ in range(len(alfabeto)):
    while True:
        checked = str(random.randint(2,len(alfabeto)))
        if '0' in checked or '1' in checked or checked in cond_1:
            pass
        else:
            cond_1 += f'{checked} '
            break
    cont = list(checked)
    cont = '0'.join(cont)
    numeri += f'{cont}1'

print(numeri, len(numeri), len(alfabeto))
```

EDIT:
Looking at the answers i changed my code resolving the problem, here it is

```py
import random

input_text = input('Testo > ')
key = ''
output_text = ''
cond_1 = ''

alfabeto = list("qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM 1234567890èéòç@à°#ù§[]+*,;.:-_<>£$₽%&()=?ì^/|!ėëęēêĖËĘĒÉÈÊūûüúŪÛÜÚÙīïįíìîĪÏĮÍÌÎºōøõœöôóŌØÕŒÖÓÒãåāáâäæÃÅĀªÀÁÂÄÆßẞÇñÑ¥¢∆¶×÷π√•`~©®™✓йцукенгшщзхфывапролджэячсмитьбюЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮ⌂☻‼‰╛┐└┴┬├─┼╞╟╚╔╩╦╠═╬╧╨╤▬╥╙╘╒╓╫╪┘┌¤█▄▌▐▀αΣσ░▒▓│┤╡╢╖╕╣║╗╝¿þ¼½¾ⁿ⌠⌡≤≥±≡∩∞ΘΩð«»⌐¬¨↨↑↓→←↔₧☼♥♦♣♠♂♀♪◘○◙►◄▲▼Þ‘’“”„")
numeri = ''

for _ in range(len(alfabeto)):
    while True:
        checked = str(random.randint(2,2000))
        if '0' in checked or '1' in checked or checked in cond_1:
            pass
        else:
            cond_1 += f'{checked} '
            break
    cont = list(checked)
    cont = '0'.join(cont)
    numeri += f'{cont}1'

print(numeri, len(numeri), len(alfabeto))
```

Comment: what's this code actually supposed to be doing?  could you edit the question to explain what's going on, also explaining what correct output is would be great!

Comment: Your `for` loop runs 343 times. In each loop it takes a random int between 2 to 351. if this number has '0' or '1' in it the loop continues (this already puts down 190 options). Now let's say you got '245', now 2, 24 ,45 etc. will make you stick in the loop. At some point you get stuck with too much values in `cond_1` before the `for` ends

Comment: @Tomerikoo sounds right, maybe you could post as an answer?

Comment: @SamMason doesn't feel like much of an answer haha. more of an observation. I think OP needs to give some details on what he/she is trying to acheive in order to offer some form of a way to improve the code...

Comment: @Tomerikoo please, excuse my lack of informations, yesterday i was really tired and i wasn't going to give more infos, I marked Sam Mason's answer as the 'right one', based on your observation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if we rearrange the code a bit we can see why this never finishes.  I start by pulling out part of the inner `while` loop into a function that generates all possible values:

```
def option_gen(n):
    for i in range(2, n):
        s = str(i)
        if '0' in s or '1' in s:
            continue
        yield s

options = list(option_gen(len(alfabeto)))
```

which has 160 values, and as as Tomerikoo observed this is much less than 351 values in your list.  hence your while loop will spin after a while, appending new values to an ever growing `cond_1` string then just doing nothing useful.

we can use this function to write a more efficient version that instead fails much more quickly rather than diverging:

```
from random import shuffle

random.shuffle(options)

result = []
for _ in range(len(alfabeto)+3):
    cont = '0'.join(list(options.pop()))
    result.append(cont + '1')

numeri = ''.join(result)
```

this will throw a useful exception after a while describing why it can't make forward progress.  also note that making that `for` loop only run over something like `range(5)` will finish

Comment: I marked you answer as the 'right one' because of the explanation, I didn't quite understood the examples, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

After adding some debug to your code

```
checked = str(random.randint(2,len(alfabeto)))
print('checked ' + checked)
if '0' in checked or '1' in checked or checked in cond_1:
    if '0' in checked:
        print('0 in checked')
    elif '1' in checked:
        print('1 in checked')
    else:
        print('checked in cond_1')
    pass
```

I ran it and saw this:

```
checked 249
checked 289
checked 70
0 in checked
```

From that point, it became pretty clear that we should have broke from the `while (True)` statement. I was perplexed until I took a step back.

```
for _ in range(len(alfabeto)+3):
    while True:
```

I missed that for loop! You're running that while loop and breaking when it fails to find something that would satisfy the condition. Then, you run it again. Eventually, on one of those loops, it has racked up enough values in `cond_1` that it will stick in the while loop forever.

Comment: Yep, I screwed up. I answered it fast, because I thought I understood the problem. My bad.